# what does formal parameter using ... mean

Tags: linux, parameters

In Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment, I find function like this

```
void 
err_sys(const char *fmt, ...) 
{
}
```

what does the formal parameter using `...` mean? I think this format should be reported as an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phenomenon goes by the name of 'variadic function'.

You may want to try your favorite search engine on that term. Wikipedia has a nice article on that subject too, so you might want to take look [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) as well.

Comment: Thanks for not using a reference to a specific search engine. The world is a better place now.